# question about html, css (I'm a beginner)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 files.

1.index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. main.css

```
div::after{
    content: "123";
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

When I opened it, it shows like this:
[image]

I don't know why 123 is in the wrong place.

Comment: be specific in your selector. You don't know how many divs will be added to your html code. Add a class or ID

Answer (score 2):

You are using live-server which injects additional content, including div elements into the page.

Your CSS select **all** div elements.

---

You could change your selector to be more specific (e.g. to select divs that are members of a particular class and then add a matching `class` attribute to the div you want to select).